# Multiple file upload in laravel using intervention

Tags: laravel, upload, intervention

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class TestController extends Controller
  {
 /**
  * Show the application dashboard.
  *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
  public function index(Request $req)
 {

 if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $filename = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];
   foreach($filename as $file){

   $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file);
    $location = public_path('/images/test/' . $withoutExt);
   $img = Image::make($file)->resize('720', '404')->save($location.'.jpg');
  }
  }}}
```

I have used the `$img = Image::make(Input::file('imagefile'))->resize('720', '404')->save($location.'.jpg');` for single file and it is working fine but for multiple file uploading I am using the `$file` instead of using the `Input` then it shows the error `Image source not readable`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, please can you edit your question to show your entire controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define var as `$filename = $_FILES['imagefile']['name'];` so wouldn't that just get a string value? And string is not readable. Let's try with just `$filename = $_FILES['imagefile']`

**UPDATE**

You loop the string value from `filename` and it's not readable image.You need a few other things to work with image upload.

```
if($req->hasfile('imagefile'))
{
    foreach($req->file('imagefile') as $file)
    {
        $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $location = public_path('/images/test/' . $withoutExt);
        $img = Image::make($file)->resize('720', '404')->save($location.'.jpg');
    }
}
```

And because you use Laravel, I suggest you to just use `$req` parameter to get your request.

Comment: I tried with this too but then it gives the error as  "Array to string conversion"

Comment: alright i dont know why,but if you use laravel i suggest you to  only use $req parameter to get all request

Comment: but i figure out this becouse $file is array and in `$withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $file);` you make combine $file to string

Comment: so what is the solution